# replacing a unicode character

Tags: javascript, html, unicode, replace

I can't figure out how to remove a Unicode character using .replace(...) here's what I've tried

```
 $(elem).click(function () {
   var display = $("." + target).css('display');
   var lastChar = display == 'none' ? 'a' : '8';
   $("." + target).slideToggle(500);
   alert('index: ' + $(this).text().indexOf('&#x21c8;'));
   $(this).html($(this).html().replace('&#x21c8;','').replace('&#x21ca;','') + ' &#x21c' + lastChar + ';');
 });
```

It is adding my double arrow up and down, but indexOf is always -1, and my replace calls are not removing the Unicode character. I'm looking at this now and thinking that if I start off with one of these Unicode chars I could just replace it with the other one... If I could get replace to work at all ;-)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Are those actual unicode characters? Then you could try `"\u21c8"`.

Comment: What exactly is the text to replace? Can you add the HTML element as well?

Comment: @le_m this has solved my issue thank you! If you want to post this as an answer, I will click you as correct solution

Comment: You fetch plain text (`.text()`) but expect to find HTML (`&#x21c8;`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML entities get converted to actual unicode characters. Example:

```js
document.body.innerHTML = "&#x21c8;";


console.log(document.body.innerHTML === "\u21c8"); // true

// Instead of a unicode esape sequence, you can write the
// actual unicode character. This is safe as long as you
// specify the correct encoding for your JavaScript files:
console.log(document.body.innerHTML === "⇈"); // true
```

So when you read the `innerHTML` via `$(this).html()` or the `textContent` via `$(this).text()`, you need to look for the actual unicode character given by its unicode escape sequence `"\u21c8"` or directly `"⇈"` and not its entity `"&#x21c8;"`.

Comment: Note the actual Unicode character is `⇈` (which should work as well).

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Right, added it to the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using [String.fromCharCode()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)

> The static String.fromCharCode() method returns a string created by
>   using the specified sequence of Unicode values.

**Syntax**

`String.fromCharCode(num1[, ...[, numN]]);`

**Examples**

`myString.replace(String.fromCharCode(8648),'');` for ⇈
`myString.replace(String.fromCharCode(8650),'');` for ⇊
`myString.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(84,69,83,84);`

Comment: This is handy when comparing to code points given as a `number`. However, I'd recommend `String.fromCodePoint` which supports the full unicode range (no IE support).

Comment: Good to know, I've been working almost exclusively in Node so haven't come across this conflict, I shall make sure to switch over :)